# "Command + L" when creating question overrides browser hotkey

Tags: bug, asking-questions, google-chrome, keyboard-shortcuts

When the focus is within the text box when writing a new question, and the user presses <kbd>Command</kbd> + <kbd>L</kbd> the `Insert Hyperlink` box comes up. This overrides the functionality of chrome, which is to switch the focus to the address bar; it's a little annoying.

The intent is to write a post not leave the page, but it is quite jarring to see the site override Chrome's keyboard shortcut.

[image]

Comment: Pretty sure this is by design, but also see if Alt-D will bring you to the address bar as well.